How to share the files of Git LFS?
At work we have a pretty big machine shared by the developers (96 cores, 50+ users). They all work on (multiple) clones of only few repositories, with typically like 25GB in the .git folder. How can we reduce disk space (and speed up cloning maybe)?
I told them to set the variable GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=/shared_repo.git/objects and did a cronjob to fetch into this, but this works only partly. I'm afraid to prune there since that could leave devs without some objects.
Quite a substantial part is in the /lfs subfolders, i.e. locally cached LFS files. Is it possible to "share" local LFS files?
I want to mention: we are using BTRFS, maybe there is a cool feature with plays well together with git?

you could share onre repo and git worktree it. You meantion 25GB .git folder and git lfs. Are you asking about sharing .git or about sharing git lfs files or both?

Both. And git worktree doesn't work well with lots of submodules. Just a simple recursive clone is what they want, and ditch it all when something goes wrong.

You could do like docker layers, unionfs filesystem with base having git master.

You could use a tool like rdfind to hard-link files with same contents in the .git/objects/lfs directories. It'll still require cloning them, but at least it'll save some disk space.
